# Função ajax para controller MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, json

Tenho esta função com *array* e não estou conseguindo passar para o *controller* os valores, eu listando, ele aparece corretamente, utilizo angular.

```
  $scope.addItem = function (user) {
        $scope.items.push({
            de: $scope.total,
            ate: user.ate,
            tipo: user.tipo,
            valor: user.valor,

        });
        $scope.total = ''
        $scope.total = user.ate;
        user.ate = '';
        user.tipo = '';
        user.valor = '';
    };

 $scope.gravaItem = function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/TaxaPreco/SalvarItens',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify($scope.items),
            success: function (result) {
                console.log('Data received: ');
                console.log(result);
            }
        })
    };
```

E aqui são o resultado quando dou um `console.log($scope.items)`;

```
Array(1)
0
:
{de: "00:01", ate: "00:29", tipo: "0", valor: "5", $$hashKey: "object:3"}
```

Como posso passar esses valores para o *controller*?
E aqui é como estou tentando receber no *controller*, porém de todas as formas, nenhuma funcionou como deveria:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> SalvarItens(List<TarifasPrecosItens> nome )
    {
        var item = new TarifasPrecosItens()
        {
            De = nome[0].De,
           //De = itens.De,
           //Ate = itens.Ate,
           //Fracao = itens.,
           //RepetirACada = 0,
           //TipoValor = tipovalor,
           //Valor = valor,
           //TarifasPrecosId = 25,

        };
```

Comment: Dúvida: se `nome` é uma lista de `TarifasPrecosItens`, então por quê criar outro objeto `TarifasPrecosItens` com os dados? Não bastaria fazer algo como `var item = nome[0]`?

Comment: Eu preciso que ele receba o array para realizar os inserts na página de controller, e isto não está ocorrendo.

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta com o angular que pega os dados, para que possa entender melhor.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, altere o metodo de GET para POST, declare seu Controller com [HttpPost] e tente da maneira a seguir..

```
var varArray = new Array();
//CRIE SEU ARRAY AQUI na varArray...

 $scope.gravaItem = function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/TaxaPreco/SalvarItens',
            traditional: true,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: { 'varArray': varArray },
            success: function (result) {
                console.log('Data received: ');
                console.log(result);
            }
        })
    };
```

no controller

```
public async Task<ActionResult> SalvarItens(List<TarifasPrecosItens> varArray)
```

verifique também se a estrutura do array é a mesma, e tente ver as mensagens de erro nos logs...

Comment: Não entendi a parte de criar o array, sendo que eu pego a função no angular, que já tem o array.

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta com o angular que pego os dados.